# ASM 6809 RTS won't return after branch

Tags: assembly, 6800

Through this useful website:

[6809  emulator](http://6809.uk/)

I'm learning ASM for the topic's title microprocessor.

Now, loading the "Hello World" sample the rts works.

Now if I manipulate simpler thing like this:

```
start:
    clrb
    jsr print
    clra
    rts
 

print:
    puls a,x,y
    rts
```

The flow won't come back after the label "print"'s JSR.
I was expecting coming back at "clra", but won't.

Can't understand why.
Is the compiler inaccurate or there's something I'm missing?

Comment: `puls` removes things from the stack that you did not even put there. In particular, it removes the return address so poor `rts` has no idea where to go.

Comment: Are you Jester from the MD Asm Website?
Anyway it's right! without puls the stack is able to help the poor rts ;-)
If you answer I'll upvote you!

Comment: No, that must be somebody else.

Comment: The helloworld example has puls but works.
Why?

Comment: Because it has a `pshs a,x,y` so it puts things on the stack that it can later pull.

Comment: Right.  Every `puls` has to be matched with an equivalent `pshs` (except for folks doing weird stuff, which you are not).